# (0x800703E3) The io operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream, comexception

I faced a problem that i couldn't solve nowadays. If you share your opinions, i'll be appriciated.

The problem about streaming file.

For example, user comes from url with a queryString parameter that identify the file to stream.

And then, read the file from database succesfully. After that, i use below codes to stream and write into response's output

```
try
{
    do
    {
         read = reader.GetBytes(6, offset, chunk, 0, chunk.Length);
         if (read > 0)
         {
            if (streamParam.Context.Response.IsClientConnected)
            {                                         
                streamParam.Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(chunk, 0, (int)read);

                streamParam.Context.Response.Flush();

                offset += read;
             }
             else read = -1;
         }
     }
     while (read > 0);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    streamParam.Context.Response.End();
}
```

The most important thing is, i can't reproduce the error in debugging environment. But when i publish the website to server, i faced errors thousands times in Event Viewer.

I Shared the event log without stack trace in case of provide some tips or something like that,

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException Page: file_streamer.aspx?fId=12312 Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. StackTrace:    at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  at webproj.file_streamer_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) 
  Source: System.Web InnerException: 
  System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): An error occurred while communicating with the remote host. The error code is 0x800703E3. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800703E3): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E3)
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) An error occurred while communicating with the remote host. The error code is 0x800703E3.    
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) DataDll The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E3)
```

P.S. : I researched it, server updates sp 2 and com port reset. It didn't worked.
Also i read about IsClientConnected but it's currently in the code.

Any help will be great, thanks,

Comment: Is it possible that `IsClientConnected` is **becoming false** as you flush to the (now disconnected) response?

Comment: Consider adding some logging to your `catch` block to see what `exc` was.

Comment: @mjwills  , i already catch the log and i wrote the exception in question. Maybe IsClientConnected is becoming false right before Flush. I'll give it a try. Thanks for recommendations.

Comment: You aren't logging where I suggested though. My concern is that `streamParam.Context.Response.End();` is throwing a **new exception** and hiding the original one.

Comment: i see you think it's not the original exception, Response.End is throwing the second exception. Thanks for recommendation.